# How wide should a workbench top's overhang be to accomodate clamp-on vises and work lamps?

Tags: tools, bench

Is 2" (5 cm) of workbench top overhang enough to accomodate most clamp-on vises and work lamps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should generally be enough. If you happen to run into a vise or lamp that wants a little more, you could edge-laminate an additional buffer strip onto the bend in that spot.

Comment: In the end I made the overhang 6 cm wide. The clamp-on vise with largest clamp-throat-depth I've found is PanaVise 311 with clamp-throat-depth of 5.87 cm, though I doubt I'll need to clamp that deep on a bench that's only 3/4" thin. Typical clamp-on vises do indeed have clamp-throat-depth of less than 2".

Answer (score 1):

I would go further in the event that you want to clamp deep throat clamps or woodworkers clamps.  Hand screw clamps can be 6" or more.  Keep that in mind for the future. What about a single side with a deeper inset for specialty clamps?

Comment: I probably should add that I am building a 3/4" thin electronics bench, so even the clamp-on vise scenario is not very likely (I use Panavise for holding PCBs) but this information will come useful to those wanting to build a woodworking bench. Thanks.